# Measure network time in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-execution-plan

Question raised just out of curiosity while working on an SQL query over a VPN connection. VPN is slow hence query was also performing slow. But I don't have direct access to the Database Server, so to test queries I need to run them through VPN :(

Is there any way to eliminate time taken by network lag due to VPN and know the actual time taken by my query? without making a copy of database and bringing it to my local system/network.

Comment: The query execution time in the lower right corner of SSMS should be actual execution time, and not affected by VPN.   Alternately, you could run a profiler trace, and look at the execution time on the server.

Comment: Not really my area of expertise, but can you ask someone to run the query on the server to get the execution time and you can compare the results?

Comment: @TabAlleman that time does get affected if your SSMS is connected to a remote server like in my case.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz, yes that is what I have been doing till now but it adds a dependency on my work. If that person is not available I cannot get actual time that is why I want a workaround to it if possible.

Comment: @yogi well a profiler trace should definitely be immune to any form of client/vpn speed.

Comment: Pulling it down locally would totally defeat the purpose of execution time because it would be against different hardware on a different environment. You might need to create 2 datetime variables. Populate the startTime with getdate() before your query, then EndTime after your query. You can then tell the time even with slow VPN lag.

Answer (score 0):

You network performance is totally dependent on your infrastructure.

For identifying execution time you can use the TIME Statistics. 
Run below query to set it on

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
```

Now run your query.
If you switch to "Messages" table of the results you will see something like below. Which is your execution time.

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```